# Adding elements to a Hash Map

Tags: java, hash, dictionary, addition, bucket

I was to draw a diagram of a hash table, size 6, after these functions were ran.

add (13) add(21) add(7) add(25)

I'm very unfamiliar with hash tables, but I came up with this.

(7)(13)(21)(25)( )( )

I know that when you add an element to a hash, it is assigned a specific hash code, but I dont understand how to find this. Can someone explain this to me?

Comment: Don't think of a `HashMap` with indexes. It is unordered, and therefore has no indexing system that you can directly access. A `TreeMap` might be better suited to your needs, if order is important.

Answer (score 0):

To build on @HovercraftFullOfEels answer, *not* implementing `hashCode()` properly in an object, will cause `HashMap` to behave badly when that object is added to it. In other words, a pre-requisite to using `HashMap` is that all potential members have properly implemented `hashCode()`.

Here is some more information on implementing `hashCode()`: https://www.google.com/search?q=implementing+hashcode+in+java

Answer (score 0):

define your table like

```
 HashMap newMap = new Hashmap();
```

then to place elements inside you do

```
 newMap.put(1, "what ever");
```

Comment: map*

I agree, a hashmap isnt the wya to go for this

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, hash tables require two arguments to actually assign values. A hash table works like this:

```
hashtable.add(key, value);
```

The key is run through a hash function, and the value is placed into an array at the index provided by the hash function, like so:

```
public class FauxHashTable {
    Object[] storage;

    public FauxHashTable(int size)
    {
        storage = new Object[size];
    }

    public void add(Object key, Object value)
    {
        storage[hashFunction(key)] = value;
    }

    public int hashFunction(Object o)
    {
        // Does some magic and returns a unique identifying integer of the object! A mathematical function that returns a different integer for EVERY object put in!
    }
}
```

So, your question doesn't make sense to me because you give an add function with only one argument. I think the fact that you added the Java tag is confusing a lot of the answerers here because when one says hash table with Java, one usually means the HashMap class. HashMap is an implementation of a hash table, but I don't think it's quite what you're asking about here.

Since you say "I was to draw", I assume this is homework and so I'm going to try and not straight up give you the answer.